# how much benefit is there of working as a predoctoral research assistant

Tags: phd, application, research-assistantship

I would like to do a PhD in a machine learning related topic and want to enhance my resume. I am considering looking for roles as volunteer research assistant and was wondering whether the experience would be beneficial if I do manage to find one. From what I've read online a lot of what predoctoral research assistants do involve menial tasks (cleaning up data) and wasn't sure if this would strengthen my application.

I'd hope to look for a research role in an area directly related to my interest. But an alternative I was considering was to just work at a job which may not have a direct connection to my interests but is slightly more financially beneficial.

I was hoping to get some advice on what would be better

Comment: Is "volunteering" even possible? I think that most places it would be disallowed by normal employment rules.

Comment: That's a good point, as far as i'm aware, from what i've read online, volunteering is possible. Maybe at minimum wage? Ultimately, if it is possible, I would like to understand the pros and cons of participating in such a role in trying to better my application

Comment: @Buffy I think the correct wording was pre-doctoral research I was wrongly under the assumption you'd need to volunteer to get such experience

Answer (score 3):

In many circumstances, yes, predoctoral research experience is an asset, in particular if you can get a strong letter of support for your graduate application, and can contribute to some publications.

Financial aspects are a consideration also, but it's hard to judge given the available information in the question.

Comment: I think thats fundamentally what I was wondering, Does a predoc researcher have the opportunity to contribute to publications or are they left up to clean up duty

Comment: In economics, having a high quality predoctoral position is one of the best ways to get admitted to top programs. I am not sure about ML but in my field it 1) exposes you to research process 2) helps you to understand research challenges and pitfalls 3) helps you define more interesting questions for admissions statements 4) involves networking. You are right that tasks can be menial but they are necessary to research.

Comment: @Dawn Thanks, that's very useful advice. are these roles referred to as predoctoral research assistant or is there another term for referring to these positions

Comment: Getting a publication probably depends on the field, the group and the student.   Suggest you inquire to the groups that interest you.  Also note that if there is a publication, it may not be immediate - could take a few months or even years.

Comment: definitely not publishing but being able to contribute to some of the research that results in publication. Ultimately some first hand experience for strengthening my resume

Answer (score 2):

In my own field (neuroscience) there can be a lot of benefit to working as a "predoctoral research assistant" if you want to go to grad school, though it's rarely called that. These are jobs available to people with a BS in academic labs; often the people that take these jobs are former students at the same school (possibly they worked in the same lab for credit or as a student employee), though sometimes people get hired from other places. It's a way to gather the research experience and perhaps publication record that is necessary these days to be competitive for grad school, especially for people who haven't had a lot of research experience as an undergraduate.

You might have better luck looking for positions in an applied research area that is looking for someone with some ML experience (hopefully you have at least some experience from coursework; every single CS student and many people from other fields have several ML/AI courses these days, if not you are way behind).

A good position will have you doing more than just menial tasks/cleaning up data, though in practice pretty much *everyone* has to do those "menial tasks", whether they hold a PhD or not. The decisions made at that stage of analysis can be just as important and even more so than decisions made at later stages, it's not something to take lightly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there a more official name for such roles or is does it just depend where you apply? A lot of the positions in industry that involve ML research i've found tend to require publication/phd experience which I don't  have.

I completely agree with you about the importance of menial tasks, I meant it in the way that these tasks aren't exclusive to RA roles. I was just wondering about the opportunity of specifically helping out with the research

Comment: @questions The job title is going to vary place to place. "Junior scientist" seemed to be a common title given at my undergraduate institution, "research intern" where I work now. There may be variants depending on the specific job duties. There is also the concept of a "post-bac" which is more directly intended to prepare people for a graduate program. These are all academic positions; there may be roles in industry but it will typically be harder to gain the resume items you want to continue in academia there.

Comment: Thanks that's very useful information

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a misunderstanding. In the US, at least, there are two primary funding opportunities for doctoral students. A TA (Teaching Assistant) aids in the teaching process, often as a grader, but occasionally as an instructor. An RA (Research Assistant) aids in research in some way. Sometimes it is to assist in the running of experiments as required by the PI, but sometimes it is just funding for the candidates own research.

But both of those require that you are admitted to a degree program (usually a doctoral program). It isn't something that you do before you make an application.

Some research labs hire lab assistants but that is a different thing. They are just employees and are unlikely to see much of the conceptual background of what is happening in the lab. There might be some value in this, as you would get to see others with more responsibility doing their "thing".

Comment: "They are just employees and are unlikely to see much of the conceptual background of what is happening in the lab." - strongly disagree at least in my own field. Yeah, there might be some lab assistant jobs that are truly just "work" like cleaning floors but there are lots of positions to do actual academic work, too. Probably a better chance in smaller labs vs larger ones.

Comment: Maybe i've got the role title wrong again but I guess in that case i'm thinking of lab assistant roles that require prerequisite knowledge in the field. Would such positions not be that beneficial as experience for PhD roles?

Comment: If you can get a job with some "responsibility" and a connection to the research process it would help. [@BryanKrause](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/166821/75368) gives good advice here.